# C - Read word by word from a file and insert it in hashtable

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I'm trying to use a chaining hashtable to count the number of repetition of all words in a .txt file.
So this is what I did, here's my **header file**:

```
#ifndef _header5_
#define _header5_

typedef struct cellule {
  char cle[15]; // Cle=Word
  int valeur; // Number of occurrences of the word
  struct cellule *suivant;
} Cellule;

typedef Cellule * Liste; // type Liste

typedef struct table_hachage {
  int taille; // table length
  Liste *linkcase; // table of listes
} Table_hachage;

// type TableHacage
typedef Table_hachage *TableHachage;

/***************Methods*****/
int max(int,int);

int count_words (FILE*);

void read_words(FILE*);

TableHachage cree_table_hachage(int);

int hachage(TableHachage, char*);

int insere(TableHachage,char*);

int recherche(TableHachage, char*);

int Get_Value(TableHachage, char*);

void fill(TableHachage,FILE*);
#endif
```

and this is my implementation of the **header file**:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fnv.h"
#include "header5.h"

int max(int a,int b){
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else if(a<b)
        return b;
    else
        return a;
}


int count_words (FILE *f) {
    char word[1024];
    int count=0;
    /* assumes no word exceeds length of 1023 */
    while (fscanf(f, " %1023s", word) == 1) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void read_words(FILE *f) {
    char word[1024];
    /* assumes no word exceeds length of 1023 */
    while (fscanf(f, " %1023s", word) == 1) {
        puts(word);
    }
}

//Create Empty chaining hashtable
TableHachage cree_table_hachage(int taille) {
    int i;
    TableHachage table = (TableHachage)malloc(sizeof(Table_hachage));
    table->taille = taille;
    table->linkcase = (Liste*)malloc(table->taille * sizeof(Liste));
    for (i = 0; i < table->taille; i++)
        table->linkcase[i] = NULL;
    printf("HashTable is created\n");
    return table;
}

//Getting the hash code using FNV1 Algorithm
//it works just fine by the way.
int hachage(TableHachage table, char *cle) {
    //FNV HashCode Algorithm version 32-bits
    int codeh = fnv_32_str(cle, FNV1_32_INIT);
    return (abs(codeh) % table->taille);
}

//Insert the word in the hashtable
int insere(TableHachage table, char* cle) {
    int codeh;
    Liste liste = NULL;
    codeh = hachage(table, cle); //getting the HashCode
    liste = table->linkcase[codeh]; //getting the LinkedList at index==HashCode
    
    while (liste) {
        //In case the key is already existed we increment its value
        //which indicates the number of repetition of that word
        if (strcmp(liste->cle, cle) == 0){
            liste->valeur++;
            return 0;
        }
        liste = liste->suivant;
    }
    //if it's the first time to encounter the word
    //we insert it and give it's value 1
    if (liste == NULL) {
        liste = (Liste)malloc(sizeof(Cellule));
        strcpy(liste->cle, cle);
        liste->valeur=1;
        liste->suivant = table->linkcase[codeh];
        table->linkcase[codeh] = liste;
        return 1;
    }
}

//Search existence of a word
int recherche(TableHachage table, char *cle){
    Liste liste = table->linkcase[hachage(table, cle)];
    for (; liste; liste = liste->suivant)
        if (strcmp(cle, liste->cle) == 0)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

//Getting value of a key a.k.a number of repetition of a word
int Get_Value(TableHachage table, char *cle){
    Liste liste = table->linkcase[hachage(table, cle)];
    for (; liste; liste = liste->suivant)
        if (strcmp(cle, liste->cle) == 0)
            return liste->valeur;
}
//Fill my hashcode with words and number of repetition of that key in the file  
void fill(TableHachage table,FILE* f){
    
    char word[1024];
    /* assumes no word exceeds length of 1023 */
    while (fscanf(f, " %1023s", word) == 1) {
        insere(table,word);
    }
}
```

So my problem resides in the `fill()` function, it is almost the same as read_word() function which works just fine except instead of printing the word, I want it to be inserted in the hash table.

When I checked which part doesn't work in fill() function, I realized it never goes into the while loop. So when I search for the word, it couldn't be found.

So can anyone explains this to me?

***EDIT:***
Here's my main():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fnv.h"
#include "header5.h"

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file=fopen("fich.txt", "r");

    int n=count_words(file);
    
    
    //Creating an empty chaining hash table
    TableHachage T=cree_table_hachage(n);
    
    //fill hash table with words and its number of repetition in the text file
    fill(T,file);
    
    //student is a word in my file
    if(recherche(T,"student")==1){
        printf("found\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("couldn't be found\n");
    }
    
    int occ=Get_Value(T, "student");
    printf("Occ is: %d\n",occ);

    
    
    fclose(file);
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Is that because you have already reached end of file using the `read_word` function? It's hard to tell with no `main` or `fopen` shown.

Comment: yes you were right i've added my main(). it's the count_words() function that causes the program to not work. so for a test i've count the number of words in the file and didn't use that function and it worked. BUT still i can't come up with other function to get the number of words in a file without using fscanf() any suggestions ?

Comment: Try adding `rewind(file)` before reading it for the second time. You already reached the end in `count_words` so in `fill` there is nothing left to read. It does not start over by magic ;)

Comment: Do you really need the number of words in the file beforehand? The only place i can see your code using the number of words is for setting the size of the hash table. You could make the hash table start at some fixed size and double its size when it gets too full, for example when the number of items in the table is equal the size of the table. That would be pretty standard implementation of a hash table. Then you could read the file just once, in your fill method.

Comment: @MadKarel you're right but since i'm using a chaining hashtable i don't thikn i'll have to resize my table each time the number of items in the table equals the size of the table. BUT, in terms of complexity, and using this kind of hashtable, is your suggestion a better optimization or not ?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much for your help before i use rewind(file) all i did to fix that problem of count_word() is fclose() the file and then immediately fopen() the file again.

Comment: yeah you do not need to resize it at that precise time, but that is how standard C++ unordered_map (and C# dictionary from slightly different reason)  behave.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a solution for this problem this is what i did

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fnv.h"
#include "header5.h"

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
FILE *file=fopen("fich.txt", "r");

int n=count_wordsV2(file);
//printf("number of words is: %d\n",n);
fclose(file);

file=fopen("fich.txt", "r");

//Creating an empty chaining hash table
TableHachage T=cree_table_hachage(n);

//fill hash table with words and its number of repetition in the text file
fill(T,file);

//Get occurences of each word in text file
char* Max=Get_Occurences(T);
printf("The most repeated word is: \"%s\" with a value=%d\n",Max,Get_Value(T, Max));

//int occ=Get_Value(T,"pilots");
//printf("occ: %d\n",occ);

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```